# Using entered form data in another area with html

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to take the name someone enters in my form and use it elsewhere on the page.  So when they submit the form, on the page it directs to it will say "thank you, *_*"

I know how to do this using php, but I've set up my php to direct to a html page once it sends the email, so I was wondering if there was a way to keep this set up, and on the html page it will say the "thank you, *_*"

When I use php, I write 
($_REQUEST['name']);
to pull out the name, but is there a way to do this outside of a php page?

If there isn't, I'll just stick with how I did it in the past, but I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, and I'm wondering if it's possible, thanks!

Comment: you could try to do it with some JavaScript - but I still don't know why you should want to do it instead of renaming your .html to .php and echoing the name.

Comment: HTML are static pages so you could not pass any dynamic variables to that page. There are some other possible ways like using iframe, ajax call fro the html page etc. but they are not fesible in this case. So stick with php.

Comment: @coolpup can you post some of your html and php code so we have a better idea of what you're doing / trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a cookie in PHP and then have some Javascript pick it up and put their name in!

Answer (score 1):

You could add the name to your URL of your HTML page, like `thanks.html?name=John`, then add it to the page using JavaScript. The variable will be accessible through `location.search` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at HTML5 cross-document messaging